# application jumps to first activity

Tags: android

I'm making an activity which contains a few fragments and some media player in each fragment. I tested this app in several phones and it worked correctly. But in one phone when I go to a specific case of fragment, app jumps out to first activty. I found out the error in log cat it was this:

> E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102.

Comment: Is this even a question?

Comment: yes how can i resolve this problem which my application jumps out in some phones.i even send the log cat error

Comment: Thats java or android related ???:>

Comment: android studio i made mistake  on  writing tag

Comment: anyone can answer ? :(((((((( i'm getting crazy

Comment: share code i may help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i solved it thank you

Comment: but there is another problem when i tested it in a another phone app says unfortunately stopped and i got this two error in log: cat:E/WakeLock: release without a matched acquire and E/Watchdog: !@Sync 8477 [۰۳-۲۶ ۲۲:۵۴:۳۸.۲۸۲